It is not possible to use resources from one module in another
I have two modules in my application: app and management. I need to use some features of the app module in the management module, however, when I try to access the following error appears for the file I am trying to reference: adds module 'ace-mobile.app.main' to the dependencies of module 'ace-mobile.destao. main' and imports unresolved classes.
I have already added the dependency for the app module in the management module. And when I do the opposite (put the management module reference in the app) it works correctly.

build.gradle of the app module:
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'

android {
    namespace 'horizon.maeandroid'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "horizon.maeandroid"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 281
        versionName "7.2.19"
        multiDexEnabled true
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", "ace_" + versionName)

        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["dagger.hilt.android.module.withPackageName": "horizon.maeandroid.app"]
            }
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            resValue("string", "DNS_SENTRY", '""')
        }

        debug {
            resValue("string", "DNS_SENTRY", '""')
        }
    }

    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    flavorDimensions "version"
    productFlavors {
        beta {
            dimension "version"
            applicationIdSuffix ".beta"
            versionNameSuffix "-beta"
            buildConfigField("String", "CLIENTES_URI", '"clientes?ativo"')
        }
        production {
            dimension "version"
            buildConfigField("String", "CLIENTES_URI", '"clientes?ativo&producao"')
        }
        goiania {
            dimension "version"
            buildConfigField("String", "CLIENTES_URI", '"clientes?ativo&producao"')
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:6.1.3@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.14.1'
    implementation 'com.github.lecho:hellocharts-android:1.5.8'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:2.2.0.3.original@aar'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.3'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.9.0'
    implementation 'io.sentry:sentry-android:5.5.1'
    implementation 'com.yarolegovich:lovely-dialog:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.flexbox:flexbox:3.0.0'
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44"
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44'

}

build.gradle of the gestao module:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'

android {
    namespace 'horizon.maeandroid.gestao'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "horizon.maeandroid"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 281
        versionName "7.2.19"
        multiDexEnabled true
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", "ace_" + versionName)

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["dagger.hilt.android.module.withPackageName": "horizon.maeandroid.gestao"]
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

 dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44"
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10'

    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.14.1'
    implementation 'com.github.lecho:hellocharts-android:1.5.8'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:2.2.0.3.original@aar'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.3'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.9.0'
    implementation 'io.sentry:sentry-android:5.5.1'
    implementation 'com.yarolegovich:lovely-dialog:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.flexbox:flexbox:3.0.0'

    implementation project(':app')
}

I've tried checking the syntax in gradle but I can't find anything wrong.

what type of resources were you trying to use?? a function or file

Initially I'm trying to access an enum.
public enum StatusSyncEnum {     NOVO, EDITADO, SINCRONIZADO, DESCARTADO } 

Not yet. I can't understand why the management module can't see the app module

I just created an empty app, with two modules.
app - it is a main app module.
management - it is a second module.
I added dependency in management project:
implementation(project(":app"))

and resources from app module became available
but when I tried to add dependency in app module to use resources from management modules, I got an alert:

"Adding dependency on module
'App.management.main'  will introduce
circular dependency between modules
'App.app.main'  and
'App.management.main'. Add dependency
anyway?"

I pressed "ok", dependency added, but now app can't build.
Maybe this is your problem?

I don't think so because the correct thing to do in my project is not to have a circular dependency. Only the management module should access the app module and not the other way around.

I tested it by creating another project with a similar module structure and it worked in this project. I believe it is some gradle configuration but I can't see what is happening.

I added the productFlavors that I had in my build.gradle from the app module to the management module and it started working
